# Google Cloud dataflow dropping messages

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I have the following application that runs a data pipeline and listens to Google pubsub:

Config:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
    <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
    <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Code:

```
Pipeline p = //Initialise pipeline
p.apply("read messages", readMessage())
    .apply("log message", logMessage())

private static PubsubIO.Read<String> readMessage() {
    return PubsubIO.readStrings()
        .fromSubscription("my_subscription");
}

//Log message just logs the message
```

I faced an issue where messages were getting dropped intermittently (i.e. they were not making it to dataflow pipeline from pubsub). In order to debug, I wrote another application and made it listen to the same pubsub. Below is the config:

Config:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-pubsub</artifactId>
    <version>0.22.0-beta</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-pubsub</artifactId>
    <version>v1-rev358-1.22.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Code:

```
@Component
public class PubsubMessageReceiver implements MessageReceiver{

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PubsubMessageReceiver.class);

    @Override
    public void receiveMessage(PubsubMessage message, AckReplyConsumer consumer) {
        logger.info(message.getData().toStringUtf8());
        consumer.ack();
    }
}
```

I made it run for a couple of hours (by creating a new subscription to listen to the same topic as the original application), checked the log files and found some messages that did not make it to the dataflow pipeline.

Now, this is intermittent and I am not able to reproduce it (even with load testing). Does this have anything to do with google's beam libraries (looks like a race condition or similar)? If yes, does anyone know if this can be fixed by changing the configuration/updating the version?

Comment: Beam should not be dropping any messages. Can you give more details on how you noticed it? How does 'oldest unacked message age' look like (you can check this for your subscription on stackdriver monitoring).
If you can, please provide a job id and approximate time when you suspect some messages were dropped?

Comment: @RaghuAngadi there is no approximate time for any day. The issue is intermittent and is observed almost every day. You can get more details on it from the bug I raised with google [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64829994). Regarding oldest unacked message age, I will check it tomorrow and revert back. Also, where can I find the job id?

Comment: You can see job_id on Dataflow console. All the jobs are listed on console : https://console.cloud.google.com/dataflow. Please select right project (at the top) if you have multiple projects. It looks something like 2017-08-30_07_34_32-13869757202442646069. I commented on the google bug report you mentioned.

Comment: @RaghuAngadi job id is `2017-08-15_01_37_58-5201578847318725707` and the oldest unacked message age averages to 2 for last 1 week.